# What does return a,b do and why?

Tags: c++, return

When we use "return 4,5" in c++ it does not give error but instead returns 5 (at least 4 would be understandable as it should return the first number it encounters) . Why does this happen and can we use this to return 2 values in any way?

Here is the code that i tried

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int something()
{
    return 4,5;
}
int main()
{
    int a=0,b=0;
    a,b = something();
    cout<<a<<b<<endl;
}
```

also in the above code for some reason 5 is assigned to b instead of a

Comment: _"it should return the first number it encounters"_ Why's that then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how comma operator works - it evaluates all the operands and returns the last one.

Unfortunately, C++ does not have built-in `tuple` (like `int`, `double`, etc.) type, so, it is impossible to return more than one value from the function. However, you could use wrapper type `std::tuple` and then unpack it using `std::tie` function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, int> something()
{
    return {1, 2};
}

int main()
{
    int a=0, b=0;
    std::tie(a, b) = something();

    std::cout << a << b << std::endl;
}
```

This is a little bit overhead for two variables, though.

Comment: Or maybe `auto [a, b] = something();` :-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That's C++17...

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm interested and terrified at the same time.

Comment: I have next to no knowledge of what's coming up in C++17. Only just migrating our production environment to C++11! (Blame widely-used enterprise systems with support for many years yet whose default compiler is still GCC 4.4)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You should be. It's [dcl.decomp] in the WD.

Comment: niiice ,tie is really handy for making the code more readable ,instead of streaching it out on multiple lines

Comment: @KerrekSB: My Ctrl+F finds no match in N4594. Nor for "`auto [`".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What outdated nonsense is that -- look at [N4604](http://wg21.link/n4604)!

Comment: @KerrekSB: Oh dear lord.

Answer (score 2):

It's using the built-in comma operator (since these are not user defined types). For user defined types it would be calling `operator,()` (the comma operator).

The comma operator evaluates both sides of the operator and returns the result of the latter. Which is why you get 5 and not 4 as the result.

As to *why* it is done here I cannot say - seems silly.

Comment: It most certainly isn't calling `operator,()`, as these are values of a built-in type. It's the comma operator, but it's definitely not resulting in a call to any `operator,()`.

Comment: No functions are called for the code in question.

Comment: Ok, ok, it's using the default, built-in comma operator in this case, but that's a detail.

Comment: If by "a detail" you mean "the truth" then yes

Comment: No, that's a pretty big deal. The built-in comma operator has different ordering semantics than a function call, for example.

Comment: For the OP to understand what is going on it makes no difference. But you are of course correct.

Comment: For the OP to understand what is going on it makes a huge difference. You're misteaching. Don't we have enough of that in our OPs' schools? :(

Comment: I'll edit the answer. Better now?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: It would only be calling a function *if the user defined an overload*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return two values, return a `std::vector` with them. Maybe a `std::pair`, or a class. As far as why, this is just how C++ works. Comma is just an operator, like + or -. It discards its left operand and returns the right one. `return` returns the value of its expression from the function. The rest you can figure out yourself.

Comment: The comma operator also *evaluates* its left operand.